# CVXOPT for convex optimization does not converge

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cvxopt, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve a nonlinear convex optimization problem of the following form `c'x + f(x)`  subject to some affine constraints. Before that I wanted to make sure that I can solve a simple problem without `f(x)`. Since I have the analytical first and second derivative of the problem I want to use them to get faster results. I am trying to use cvxopt to solve the problem. I wrote following code for the problem.

```
maximize Sum(l*r_i*x_i,i=1:n-1)
s.t.   sum(x_i, i=1:n) =1
       x_i -v_i*x_n<=0 i=1,...,n-1
       0<=x_i<=1
```

But I cannot achieve optimal solution to this using cvxopt. If I use the modeling functionality of cvxopt, I can solve it easily. But unfortunately, I am not sure if I can provide analytical first and second derivative using that.

Here is the code for the problem

```
from cvxopt import matrix, log, div, spdiag, solvers, spmatrix
import numpy as np

def F(x=None, z = None):
    m,n = A.size
    if x is None: return 0,matrix(0.5,(n,1))
    if (min(x) <0. or max(x)>1.): return None
    f = matrix(-l*r.T*x[:-1])
    Df = -l*matrix(np.append(r,0)).T
    if z is None: return f,Df
    H = matrix(0.0, (n,n))
    return f,Df,H


dd = 6
l = 19
C = 1.2 * l
theta = 1.25
v = [4.99, 4.66, 3.84, 4.58, 2.54, 1.83]
r = matrix(np.array([max(0.8, 1 - 0.04 * i) for i in range(dd)]))
A = matrix(np.zeros([dd, dd + 1], dtype=float))
for i in range(dd):
    A[i, i] = 1.0
    A[i, -1] = -v[i]
b = matrix(np.zeros([dd, 1], dtype=float))
A_eq = matrix(np.ones([1, dd + 1], dtype=float))
b_eq = matrix([1.0])

solvers.cp(F,G=A,h=b, A= A_eq,b=b_eq).solve()
```

I am probably making some mistake in this code. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did not check your F, but i highly think there is something wrong within it as the solver-behaviour is strange (increasing it's and iterative-refinement won't help). Your problem looks so simple in math-form, that i highly recommend trying out cvxpy, which has nicer modelling and imho the better solvers (incl. cvxopt, while not beeing that tunable like a-priori KKT-solvers).